# Fluentd - Azure Event Hubs input plugin

Tags: azure-eventhub, fluentd

Some of the Azure services we're using (e.g. APIM, Function Apps, etc) are sending logs to Azure Event Hubs.

How do I consume these logs in Fluentd?

From the Fluentd [plugins page](https://www.fluentd.org/plugins/all#input-output), I can't see any *input* plugins specifically for Azure Event Hubs. There is however a [Kafka](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-kafka) plugin that *might* work - not sure.
There is also an Azure Event Hubs *output* plugin - see [here](https://github.com/htgc/fluent-plugin-azureeventhubs) - but I'm looking for an *input* plugin.
Logstash (which is an alternate log forwarding solution) has an Azure Event Hubs input plugin - see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-azure_event_hubs.html) - but we're looking to use Fluentd for a few other reasons.

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Fluent/Fluentd provides a unified log collection solution. Why do you need to read an Azure Event Hubs source? That is almost the opposite what Fluent designed for.

Comment: We need to collect logs from a number of different sources including (but not limited to) containerized/bespoke services running in AKS, and Azure services like APIM, Function/Logic Apps, etc. I was thinking of Fluentd for log filtering, transform/standardization, enrichment, etc. and then routing/forwarding the logs to several destinations inc our centralized logging solution (Splunk), as well as Blob storage (for cheaper long term retention). Azure Event Hubs comes into the picture so that we can complete the pipeline for Azure Services.... otherwise how would we get APIM logs to Fluentd?

Comment: I think you are looking for Event Hubs metrics diagnostic/operational logs; not the actual stream from the service. Can you confirm?

Comment: Not 100% I quite understand your question, but basically I want to stream monitoring data to an event hub and then subsequently on to external partner (Splunk) - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/stream-monitoring-data-event-hubs. Fluentd is the forwarding layer - would read the event hub and do some additional filtering/transformation/etc before routing to Splunk/Blob-storage/MSSP... hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Fluent is not the right tool for that. Splunk already provides data collectors for Azure services including Azure Event Hubs. Have you checked it? Here is an example you can take a look - https://www.splunk.com/en_us/blog/platform/splunking-azure-event-hubs.html

Comment: Nice. Thanks Serkant. Note: we're looking at use something like the banzai logging operator in K8s/AKS - see https://banzaicloud.com/docs/one-eye/logging-operator, so we'll already have Fluentd for application logs in AKS. We'd probably like to standardize log format - can we do transformation (and filtering) in the splunk add-on? Also we'll probably need to route to multiple destination outputs e.g. Splunk/Blob-storage/MSSP, which is why I was thinking the logs to event hubs would go through the exact same Fluentd pipeline...

Comment: I am not a Splunk expert, you can check their documentation for Splunk related questions. Regarding Banzai Cloud, Azure Event Hubs would be an output resource only. Luckily Fluent supports Kafka input. It should work with Event Hubs as well. Have you checked it? https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-kafka

Comment: yes - I've checked the kafka plugin. It can be used as both input and output. The log pipeline that I was originally thinking for something like APIM or function app would be: APIM -> event hub -> fluentd (where we do filtering/transformation) -> multiple outputs (e.g. Splunk, blob storage, MSSP). The log pipeline for containerized services in AKS would be: containerized app -> fluent bit -> fluentd -> multiple outputs (e.g. Splunk, blob storage, MSSP). This way we don't have to duplicate the forwarding logic (inc. filtering, transformation, enrichment, output routing) in multiple places...

Comment: ... but you're suggesting not to route logs for Azure services like APIM and function apps this way - instead you suggest using the Splunk addon. This looks good, but my only concern would be that we might need to duplicate some of the logic (such as filtering, transformation, enrichment, output routing) in multiple places... if it all goes through fluentd, we have no duplication of this logic... thoughts...

Comment: Initially I didn't know Fluent supported Kafka as an input source. Now it makes more sense to avoid logic duplication and have all services under unified Fluent experience.